# Je (ne) dirai rien que la vérité

Tags: grammaire, négation

Je sais qu'il faut utiliser `ne` ou `n'` entre le pronom et le verbe lorsque ce dernier est suivi de mots tels que `pas`, `plus`, `jamais`, `aucun`, `guère`, etc.

Par exemple :

> - Je **n**'ai **pas** de chance.
> - Je **ne** l'ai **jamais** vu.
> - Je **ne** vois **aucun** intérêt.

Je sais également qu'il faut les utiliser pour indiquer une négation et seulement une négation, au risque de changer le sens de la phrase :

> - Je **n**'ai **plus** de stylos. (je n'en ai plus aucun)
> - J'ai **plus** de stylos. (j'en ai davantage)

Sachant cela, comment peut-on répondre à la dernière partie de la célèbre question « Jurez-vous de dire la vérité, toute la vérité, rien que la vérité » ?

> 1. Je dirai **rien** que la vérité
> 2. Je **ne** dirai **rien** que la vérité

Entre les deux mon cœur balance.

Si on considère que, dans ce contexte, `rien` est synonyme de `uniquement`, je préfère omettre le `ne` (réponse 1) :

> Je dirai **uniquement** la vérité.

Si on considère que `rien` exprime l'exclusion des choses qui ne sont pas des vérités, je préfère employer le `ne` (réponse 2) :

> Je **ne** dirai **rien**, si ce n'est la vérité.

Pensez-vous que le `ne` est préférable ou à éviter ?

Si les deux formulations sont correctes, sont-elles un peu différentes (par exemple une formulation insiste sur le sujet et l'autre sur l'objet) ?

P.S. : je sais qu'à l'oral il est fréquent d'omettre le `ne` pour une phrase négative, mais j'espère que nous sommes d'accord que cette facilité n'est guère intéressante ici.

Comment: Ça n'est pas `ne ...  rien` l'expression mais `ne ... que`. La bonne formulation est `Je ne dirai que la vérité`. Le `rien` peut être omis.

Answer (score 4):

En effet, cette tournure semble créer chez l'utilisateur du langage une impression de vague, cette présente remarque  que je fais étant motivée par l'appréhension personnelle que j'en ai, corroborée par votre question.

Tout d'abord, « Je dirai rien que la vérité. » ne peut être que familier.

Il faut comprendre que la locution « ne … rien que » avec le sens

> « 1. Uniquement, seulement. Synonyme : ne... que »

donné par le TLFi, est bien celle qui doit communiquer l'idée de « uniquement ».

Elle peut être remplacé par « rien d'autre que », ce qui renforce son sens perçu et le rend indubitable. Il ne faut pas dire que « rien » signifie « uniquement » dans ce contexte, c'est vraiment « rien que » qui signifie cela et en plus dans une langue relâchée.

Il s'agit sans aucun doute de l'usage relâché suivant avec lequel on ne peut pas ne pas être familier tellement il est fréquent et ce serait cet usage qui induirait des impressions trompeuses. La signification est bien « uniquement ».

- Il fait **rien que** s'amuser. Elle apporte **rien que** la feuille de cours et ne prend pas de notes. Il chantent **rien que** du yé-yé. Elle dit **rien que** ce qui te plait pas. …

Il existe, de plus, la locution courante suivante ;

> (TLFi) 2. Rien que + syntagme prép. [Ce qui est désigné par le syntagme prép. suffit pour produire l'effet indiqué par le verbe princ.]
>
> - Je frémis rien qu'en y pensant. (Il me suffit d'y penser pour frémir.)

Elle signifie aussi « uniquement » (quelques exemples de plus pour mieux la connaitre);

- **Rien que** l'apparence les en a détourné.
- **Rien qu**'à sentir cette sauce je ne veux pas en manger. (*Uniquement son odeur me dit que ce n'est pas bon*)
- Il a trouvé la bête malade **rien qu**'à la voir.
- Nous nous sommes tus **rien qu**'à un signe de l'œil du surveillant.

Celle-ci aussi, bien que correcte, tendrait à introduire un doute dans le sens de valider une soit disant exactitude de « rien que » en tant que « ne … rien que ».

La différence est dans la syntaxe ; « ne … rien que » est utilisé avec un verbe alors que « rien que » doit être suivi par un syntagme prépositionnel. On rejoint ici l'usage relâché et la confusion s'installe, d'où, tout au moins dans ce présent cas, l'importance de ne pas se laisser aller à cet usage.

Ma conclusion est donc que de négliger le « ne » de façon soutenue est nuisible à la préservation d'une bonne intuition du langage dans le cas présent et possiblement dans d'autres ; cependant dans des constructions courantes cela ne semble pas avoir cet effet négatif mais en gardant néanmoins le cachet d'un français familier.

Comment: Si c'est `ne … rien que` qui est synonyme de `uniquement` (nb: j'ai écrit que `rien` était synonyme de `uniquement`), je pense alors que la solution 1 que j'ai proposée n'est plus valable. Par conséquent le `ne` est préférable voire obligatoire.

Comment: @velas Du simple point de vue de la forme, pour la langue écrite ou la langue parlée dans un contexte formel, « ne » est obligatoire ; j'ai essayé d'expliquer pourquoi on pourrait avoir l'impression que ce ne serait  pas le cas ; je n'ai pas l'impression que cela soit vraiment convainquant pour vous, cependant.

Comment: @velas C'est `ne ... que` qui est synonyme de `uniquement`. Exemple : _Je ne tue que pour manger_

Answer (score 1):

J'utiliserais personnellement pour répondre à la question *« Jurez-vous de dire la vérité, toute la vérité, rien que la vérité »*:

> Je **ne** dirai **rien**, si ce n'est la vérité.

Considérer que *rien* exprime l'exclusion des choses qui ne sont pas des vérités est selon moi le choix le plus juste dans l'exemple donné.

Comment: L'exclusion est exprimée par « si  ce n'est » qui signifie « sauf » (Je ne dirai rien **sauf** la vérité.) ; c'est la vérité qui est exclue du silence ; rien n'exclu rien et exprime le silence au moyen de « dire ». « rien » tout seul exclu tout propos (avec « dire »).